# Using normals in a cube in Webgl

Tags: javascript, geometry, webgl, normals

I have managed to draw a rubix cube using webgl. For this I have used 27 small cubes with their corresponding color. But, now I have tried to add the use of normals to use the lighting and I have obtained fatal results and I cannot see where the error is.

The result obtained without using normals is:
[Withous normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqh3k.png)

And with normals:
[With normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybLAR.png)

The code I've used to create each small cube is:

```
class Cubo {
    constructor(i, j, k) { //i, j, k --> posicion inicial --> i = x, j=y, k=z

        this.vertices = [
            - LADO_CUBO/2 ,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //0
            - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //1
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //2
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //3


            + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //4
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //5
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //6
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //7

            + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //8
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //9
            - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //10
            - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //11

            - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //12
            - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //13
            - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //14
            - LADO_CUBO/2 ,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //15

            - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //16
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //17
            - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //18
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //19

            - LADO_CUBO/2 ,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //20
            - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //21
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2, //22
            + LADO_CUBO/2,  - LADO_CUBO/2,  + LADO_CUBO/2, //23

        ];

        this.indices = [
            //cara delantera
            0, 2,1,    2, 0, 3,   

            //cara derecha
            4,5,6,      6,5,7,

            //cara trasera
            9,10,8,     9,11,10,

            //cara izq
            13,14,12,   14,13,15,

            //cara arriba
            16,18,17,   17,18,19,

            //Cara abajo
            20,21,23,   22,23,21
        ];

        this.normals = [
            0,0,1,
            0,0,1,
            0,0,1,
            0,0,1,

            1,0,0,
            1,0,0,
            1,0,0,
            1,0,0,

            0,0,-1,
            0,0,-1,
            0,0,-1,
            0,0,-1,
            
            -1,0,0,
            -1,0,0,
            -1,0,0,
            -1,0,0,

            0,1,0,
            0,1,0,
            0,1,0,
            0,1,0,

            0,-1,0,
            0,-1,0,
            0,-1,0,
            0,-1,0,
        ]

        this.matrix = new Mat4([
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ]);


        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.k = k;

        this.colores = []; //en medio --> no se ve
        

        if(i==1){ //Amarillo
            for(var t = 4; t < 8; t++){
                let pos = t*4;
                this.colores[pos] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 1] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 2] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 3] = 1;
            }
            
        }
        else if(i == -1){
            for(var t = 12; t < 16; t++){
                let pos = t*4;
                this.colores[pos] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 1] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 2] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 3] = 1;
            }
        }

        if(j==1){
            for(var t = 16; t < 20; t++){
                let pos = t*4;
                this.colores[pos] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 1] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 2] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 3] = 1;
            }
        }
        else if(j == -1){
            for(var t = 20; t < 24; t++){
                let pos = t*4;
                this.colores[pos] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 1] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 2] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 3] = 1;
            }
        }

        if(k == 1){
            for(var t = 8; t < 12; t++){
                let pos = t*4;
                this.colores[pos] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 1] = 0.5;
                this.colores[pos + 2] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 3] = 1;
            }
        }
        else if(k == -1){
            for(var t = 0; t < 4; t++){
                let pos = t*4;
                this.colores[pos] = 1;
                this.colores[pos + 1] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 2] = 0;
                this.colores[pos + 3] = 1;
            }
        }

        for(var t=0; t<24; t++){
            let pos = t*4;
            this.colores[pos + 3] = 1;
        }

        this.Trasladar(this.i*LADO_CUBO,this.j*LADO_CUBO,-this.k*LADO_CUBO);


        this.positionBuffer = undefined;
        this.colorBuffer = undefined;
        this.indexBuffer = undefined;
        
    }
```

The code I've used to draw it is:

```
dibujar(program) {
        if (typeof this.positionBuffer === 'undefined') {
    
            this.positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.positionLocation);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
            this.colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.colorBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.colores), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.colorLocation);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
            this.normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

            // Asignar valores de normales
            
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.normalAttributeLocation);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.normalAttributeLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            

            this.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            
        } 
    
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.positionBuffer);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.colorBuffer);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalBuffer);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);

        gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.normalAttributeLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.matrixLocation, false, this.matrix);
        
        
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
```

and using the following as vertex shader

```
<script id="vertex-shader-3d" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 a_position;
        attribute vec4 a_color;
        attribute vec3 a_normal; // Agrega un atributo de normales
        varying vec4 v_color;
        varying vec3 v_normal; // Declara una variable varying para pasar las normales al fragment shader
    
        uniform mat4 u_matrix;
        uniform mat4 u_viewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
    
        void main() {
          // Multiply the position by the matrix.
          gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * u_viewMatrix * u_matrix * a_position;
          v_color = a_color;
    
          // Calcular la normal en el espacio de vista y pasarla al fragment shader
          v_normal = mat3(u_viewMatrix * u_matrix) * a_normal;
        }
    </script>
```

being the constructor of program:

```
class Program{
    constructor(){
        var vertexShaderSource = document.querySelector("#vertex-shader-3d").text;
        var fragmentShaderSource = document.querySelector("#fragment-shader-2d").text;
                
        const vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
        const fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);
        this.program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
        this.matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "u_matrix");
        this.viewMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "u_viewMatrix");
        this.viewProjectionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, "u_projectionMatrix");
        this.positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "a_position");
        this.colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_color');
        this.normalAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_normal');

        this.viexMatrix = new Mat4([
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ]);
        this.projectionMatrix = new Mat4([
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        ]);
    }

    setViewMat( new_view_mat ){
      this.viexMatrix = new_view_mat;
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.viewMatrixLocation, false, program.viexMatrix);
    }

    setProjMat( new_proj_mat  )
    {
      this.projectionMatrix = new_proj_mat;  
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.viewProjectionLocation, false, program.projectionMatrix);
 
    }
}
```

the goal is to make all the colors of the faces look sharp and the cube get lit using normals.

Comment: Consider editing your question to add more descriptions of the problem that you have encountered.